# Angular 8 route params in route data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular8

I have the following route:

```
{
path: 'introducer/:introducerId/branches/create',
component: IntroducerBranchesCreateComponent,
data: {
  pageTitle: 'Add branch',
  breadcrumbs: [
    { title: 'Branches', link: '/introducer/' + :introducerId + '/branches' },
    { title: 'Add', link: '' },
  ],
},
},
```

In the breadcrumbs array I would like to populate the link property using the route param `:introducerId` but have been unable to do so. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this would work but you could try something

```
{
    path: 'introducer/:introducerId/branches/create',
    component: IntroducerBranchesCreateComponent,
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Add branch',
        breadcrumbs: () => {
            const id = this.getIntroducerId();

            return [
                { title: 'Branches', link: `/introducer/${id}/branches` },
                { title: 'Add', link: '' },
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

And then add the method `getIntroducerId` to your component, and make your usage of `data.breadcrumbs` call it as a function instead of just using the object property.